# How do I display the total number of lines in the Emacs modeline

Tags: emacs, lines-of-code, modeline

The default Emacs modeline only shows the current line number and its percentage in relation to the total line numbers. How do I make it show the line total as well?

Comment: See the alternative answer in this related thread, which uses `(format-mode-line "%l")` instead of `count-lines` in order to receive a boost in performance/speed:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/26724/2287

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This can be a little tricky, because if you update the line count all the time and have a large buffer it can make Emacs somewhat unresponsive since it's counting lines over and over.  I wrote this to take a lazy approach to counting: it only does it when the file is first read in or after you save/revert it.  If the buffer is modified it doesn't lie about the line count, it simply isn't shown until you save again.

```
(defvar my-mode-line-buffer-line-count nil)
(make-variable-buffer-local 'my-mode-line-buffer-line-count)

(setq-default mode-line-format
              '("  " mode-line-modified
                (list 'line-number-mode "  ")
                (:eval (when line-number-mode
                         (let ((str "L%l"))
                           (when (and (not (buffer-modified-p)) my-mode-line-buffer-line-count)
                             (setq str (concat str "/" my-mode-line-buffer-line-count)))
                           str)))
                "  %p"
                (list 'column-number-mode "  C%c")
                "  " mode-line-buffer-identification
                "  " mode-line-modes))

(defun my-mode-line-count-lines ()
  (setq my-mode-line-buffer-line-count (int-to-string (count-lines (point-min) (point-max)))))

(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'my-mode-line-count-lines)
(add-hook 'after-save-hook 'my-mode-line-count-lines)
(add-hook 'after-revert-hook 'my-mode-line-count-lines)
(add-hook 'dired-after-readin-hook 'my-mode-line-count-lines)
```

You might want to adjust `mode-line-format` to suit your taste of course, the above is what I personally prefer.